# Keras--variational auto-encoder in R studio, which part is defined as Encoder?

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, keras, variational-bayes

This is the example given on VAE, the circle part is something I do not understand. It defined the encoder part as from (X to Z_mean), but my understanding is from(x to Z). Or it just simply does not matter in this case? May I define the encoder part to be(X to Sigma) since it mean and sigma are generated in the same step?  Thank you for your help in advance!

[The link for the example below](https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/guide/keras/examples/variational_autoencoder/)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People typically use the term "encoder" to describe the network which maps $x$ to $\mu$ *and* $\Sigma$ of the posterior. In my opinion this code takes a slightly nonstandard naming approach, but names are just names and the model is the same even if you call an X a Y.

So yes, you can define whatever you want, as long as you're aware of what model the code actually corresponds to. In this case, the "encoder" isn't actually used anywhere in the code except for visualization purposes.